# How to set image src using href from parent anchor?

Tags: jquery, image, this, href, src

I have the following link which is supposed to show an image within the link when javascript is loaded:

```
<a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ae/Mad_scientist.svg" id="a">
 <img alt="no image">
</a>
```

The javascript is supposed to get the href property of the link and include it when writing the html for the image.

```
$('#a').html('<img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">image');
```

Somehow, `$(this).attr('href')` is returning `undefined`. What is wrong with this?

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PvdMq/1/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PvdMq/2/)

```
$('#a').html(function () {
   return  '<img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">image'
});
```

> A function returning the HTML content to set. Receives the index
>   position of the element in the set and the old HTML value as
>   arguments. jQuery empties the element before calling the function; use
>   the oldhtml argument to reference the previous content. Within the
>   function, this refers to the current element in the set.

Refrence

http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml

http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/

In your code

```
$('#a').html('<img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">image');
```

`$(this)` is undefined in your code.

eg.

```
$('#a').html(function () {
       return  '<img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">image'
});
```

In the above code `this` refers to current element i.e element with `id="a"`

Comment: @QuestionOverflow yeah sure updating answer in a min.

Comment: Ah.. I see, it says within `.html()` function, `this` refers to the current element in the set. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj= $("#a");
obj.html('<img src="' + obj.attr('href') + '">image');
```

Comment: because this is instantiated to nothing here.